Read multiple files parallel into separate dataframe in Pyspark
I am trying to read large txt files into dataframe. Each file is 10-15 GB in size,
as the IO is taking long time. I want to read multiple file in parallel and get them in separate dataframe.
I tried below code
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
def read_file(file_path):
    return spark.read.csv(file_path)

pool = ThreadPool(10)
df_list = pool.starmap(read_file,[[file1,file2,file3...]])


But it gives pickel error.
How can I do this?, any alternative for my requirement?
I want to read multiple file in parallel and get them in separate dataframe.

It's possible that the bottleneck is I/O from disk.  If that's the case, then multiprocessing is not going to help one bit.  It takes time to read hundreds of gigabytes from disk, no matter how many CPUs you use.

In the short term, you need to read about using if __name__=="__main__": when using multiprocessing.  That's absolutely critical.
